# io.realm.CategoryRealmProxy cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView

Tags: java, android

I want to save the ImageView to RealmDatabase so i try to convert it to byte[] but it seems it still read it as an ImageView or something.

I wanted to save this image from my spinner
[the image from spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAVwq.jpg)

here is my code onSaveExpense

```
public void onSaveExpense() {

    //TODO - BITMAP EXPENSE ICONS


    if (mCategoriesSpinnerAdapter.getCount() > 0 ) {
        if (!Util.isEmptyField(etTotal)) {
            Category currentCategory = (Category) spCategory.getSelectedItem();
            String total = etTotal.getText().toString();
            String description = etDescription.getText().toString();
            ImageView theicon =(ImageView) spCategory.getSelectedItem();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)theicon.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream imgbyte = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, imgbyte);
            byte[] expenseIcons = imgbyte.toByteArray();

            if (mUserActionMode == IUserActionsMode.MODE_CREATE) {

                //TODO - CONSTRUCTOR expenseIcons
                RealmManager.getInstance().save(new Expense(description, selectedDate,expenseIcons,mExpenseType, currentCategory, Float.parseFloat(total)), Expense.class);
            } else {
                Expense editExpense = new Expense();
                editExpense.setId(mExpense.getId());
                editExpense.setTotal(parseFloat(total));
                editExpense.setDescription(description);
                editExpense.setIconViewer(expenseIcons);
                editExpense.setCategory(currentCategory);
                editExpense.setDate(selectedDate);
                RealmManager.getInstance().update(editExpense);
            }
            // update widget if the expense is created today
            if (DateUtils.isToday(selectedDate)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ExpensesWidgetProvider.class);
                i.setAction(ExpensesWidgetService.UPDATE_WIDGET);
                getActivity().sendBroadcast(i);
            }
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
            dismiss();
        } else {
            DialogManager.getInstance().showShortToast(getString(string.error_total));
        }
    } else {
        DialogManager.getInstance().showShortToast(getString(string.no_categories_error));
    }
}
```

here is my spinner adapter

```
public class CategoriesSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {


Category[] categoriesList = null;
LayoutInflater inflater;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_ui, parent, false);
    Category category = categoriesList[position];
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(category.getImgico(),0,category.getImgico().length);
    ImageView imgview = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerimg);
    TextView title = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinnertext);
    title.setText(category.getName());
    imgview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    return row;
}
```

here is my error when clicking save button

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.jmnapps.expensetracker, PID: 9610
java.lang.ClassCastException: io.realm.CategoryRealmProxy cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
    at com.jmnapps.expensetracker.ui.expenses.NewExpenseFragment.onSaveExpense(NewExpenseFragment.java:199)
    at com.jmnapps.expensetracker.ui.expenses.NewExpenseFragment.onClick(NewExpenseFragment.java:169)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spCategory.getSelectedItem()` returns as `Category` type so you cannot cast it to `ImageView`. Look at your code here:

```
Category currentCategory = (Category) spCategory.getSelectedItem();
ImageView theicon =(ImageView) spCategory.getSelectedItem();
```

Have you seen the problem? YOu are trying to cast `getSelectedItem` to different types

EDIT:
You can change this in your `onSaveExpense()` function:

```
Category currentCategory = (Category) spCategory.getSelectedItem();
String total = etTotal.getText().toString();
String description = etDescription.getText().toString();
ImageView theicon =(ImageView) spCategory.getSelectedItem();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(currentCategory.getImgico(),0,currentCategory.getImgico().length);
ByteArrayOutputStream imgbyte = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, imgbyte);
byte[] expenseIcons = imgbyte.toByteArray();
```

Comment: I saw it thanks a lot.. now how can i also include the ImageView  
if im only using one spinner at a time.
`List<Category> categoriesList = Category.getCategoriesExpense();
        Category[] categoriesArray = new Category[categoriesList.size()];
        categoriesArray = categoriesList.toArray(categoriesArray);
        mCategoriesSpinnerAdapter = new CategoriesSpinnerAdapter(getActivity(), categoriesArray);
        mCategoriesSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(spinner_ui);
        spCategory.setAdapter(mCategoriesSpinnerAdapter);`

thats my `Category`. sorry questioning a lot.

Comment: Why don't you just assign this directly? `byte[] expenseIcons = currentCategory.getImgico()` and remove the bitmap/bytes in `onSaveExpense`

Comment: Because it will only get the Total and the Description the image will not appear when i save it.

Comment: hmm, `currentCategory.getImgico()` is already a `ByteArray` right?

Comment: yeah i just tried it again just now not working, i don't really know why that code is not working.

Comment: same result :( it only just save the total and description only.. ill just post a new question and send you the link from it for more detailed info.

Comment: here is the updated question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54705295/saved-imageview-not-appearing-after-saving-it-as-byte