# Saved ImageView not appearing after saving it as byte[]

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, realm-database

I am planning to save this ImageView :

[image: Screenshot1]

to my RealmDatabase, but the image is not appearing when I want to retrieve it. it should appear here:

[image: Screenshot2]

here is the my onSaveExpense code

```
public void onSaveExpense() {

    //TODO - BITMAP EXPENSE ICONS


    if (mCategoriesSpinnerAdapter.getCount() > 0 ) {
        if (!Util.isEmptyField(etTotal)) {
            Category currentCategory = (Category) spCategory.getSelectedItem();
            String total = etTotal.getText().toString();
            String description = etDescription.getText().toString();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(currentCategory.getImgico(),0,currentCategory.getImgico().length);
            ByteArrayOutputStream imgbyte = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, imgbyte);
            byte[] expenseIcons = imgbyte.toByteArray();


            if (mUserActionMode == IUserActionsMode.MODE_CREATE) {

                //TODO - CONSTRUCTOR expenseIcons
                RealmManager.getInstance().save(new Expense(description, selectedDate,expenseIcons,mExpenseType, currentCategory, Float.parseFloat(total)), Expense.class);
            } else {
                Expense editExpense = new Expense();
                editExpense.setId(mExpense.getId());
                editExpense.setTotal(parseFloat(total));
                editExpense.setDescription(description);
                editExpense.setIconViewer(expenseIcons);
                editExpense.setCategory(currentCategory);
                editExpense.setDate(selectedDate);
                RealmManager.getInstance().update(editExpense);
            }
            // update widget if the expense is created today
            if (DateUtils.isToday(selectedDate)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ExpensesWidgetProvider.class);
                i.setAction(ExpensesWidgetService.UPDATE_WIDGET);
                getActivity().sendBroadcast(i);
            }
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
            dismiss();
        } else {
            DialogManager.getInstance().showShortToast(getString(string.error_total));
        }
    } else {
        DialogManager.getInstance().showShortToast(getString(string.no_categories_error));
    }
}
```

Here is my CategoriesSpinnerAdapter code

```
public class CategoriesSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {


Category[] categoriesList = null;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CategoriesSpinnerAdapter(Activity context, Category[] categoriesList) {
    super(context, R.layout.spinner_ui, categoriesList);
    this.categoriesList = categoriesList;
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_ui, parent, false);
    Category category = categoriesList[position];
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(category.getImgico(),0,category.getImgico().length);
    ImageView imgview = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinnerimg);
    TextView title = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinnertext);
    title.setText(category.getName());
    imgview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    return row;
}
```

here is my BaseExpenseAdapter code (The Cardview Result)

```
public class BaseExpenseAdapter<VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends BaseExpenseRecyclerViewAdapter<BaseExpenseAdapter.BaseExpenseViewHolder> {

protected List<Expense> mExpensesList;
protected int lastPosition = -1;
protected int colorExpense;
protected int colorIncome;
protected String prefixExpense;
protected String prefixIncome;
private String titleTransitionName;

protected BaseViewHolder.RecyclerClickListener onRecyclerClickListener;

public BaseExpenseAdapter(Context context, BaseViewHolder.RecyclerClickListener onRecyclerClickListener) {
    this.mExpensesList = ExpensesManager.getInstance().getExpensesList();
    this.onRecyclerClickListener = onRecyclerClickListener;
    this.colorExpense = ExpenseTrackerApp.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccentRed);
    this.colorIncome = ExpenseTrackerApp.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccentGreen);
    this.prefixExpense = ExpenseTrackerApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.expense_prefix);
    this.prefixIncome = ExpenseTrackerApp.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.income_prefix);
    this.titleTransitionName = ExpenseTrackerApp.getContext().getString(R.string.tv_title_transition);
}

@Override
public BaseExpenseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_expense_item, parent, false);
    return new BaseExpenseViewHolder(v, onRecyclerClickListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(BaseExpenseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setSelected(isSelected(position));
    final Expense expense = mExpensesList.get(position);
    Bitmap bitmaps = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(expense.getIconViewer(), 0, expense.getIconViewer().length);
    holder.iconExpenses.setImageBitmap(bitmaps);
    String prefix = "";
    switch (expense.getType()) {
        case IExpensesType.MODE_EXPENSES:
            holder.tvTotal.setTextColor(colorExpense);
            prefix = String.format(prefixExpense, Util.getFormattedCurrency(expense.getTotal()));
            break;
        case IExpensesType.MODE_INCOME:
            holder.tvTotal.setTextColor(colorIncome);
            prefix = String.format(prefixIncome, Util.getFormattedCurrency(expense.getTotal()));
            break;
    }
    if (expense.getCategory() != null)holder.tvCategory.setText(expense.getCategory().getName());
    if (expense.getDescription() != null && !expense.getDescription().isEmpty()) {
        holder.tvDescription.setText(expense.getDescription());
        holder.tvDescription.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.tvDescription.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
    holder.tvTotal.setText(prefix);
    holder.itemView.setTag(expense);
    holder.iconExpenses.setImageBitmap(bitmaps);
    ViewCompat.setTransitionName(holder.tvTotal, titleTransitionName);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mExpensesList.size();
}

public void updateExpenses(List<Expense> mExpensesList) {
    this.mExpensesList = mExpensesList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

protected void setAnimation(BaseExpenseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (position > lastPosition) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ExpenseTrackerApp.getContext(), R.anim.push_left_in);
        holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
}

public static class BaseExpenseViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder {

    public TextView tvCategory;
    public TextView tvDescription;
    public TextView tvTotal;
    public ImageView iconExpenses;

    public BaseExpenseViewHolder(View v, RecyclerClickListener onRecyclerClickListener) {
        super(v, onRecyclerClickListener);
        iconExpenses = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.expenseico);
        tvCategory = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_category);
        tvDescription = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_description);
        tvTotal = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
    }

}
```

and here is my Expense entities

```
public class Expense extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private String id;
private byte[] iconViewer;
private String description;
private Date date;
private @IExpensesType int type;
private Category category;
private float total;

public Expense() {
}





public Expense(String description, Date date ,byte[] iconViewer, @IExpensesType int type, Category category, float total) {
    this.description = description;
    this.iconViewer = iconViewer;
    this.date = date;
    this.type = type;
    this.category = category;
    this.total = total;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public byte[] getIconViewer() {
    return iconViewer;
}

public void setIconViewer(byte[] iconViewer) {
    this.iconViewer = iconViewer;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public float getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(float total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: If it is not related to security concerns, I will suggest to save the image in the phones's storage and only save the path of the image in your database.

Comment: @Vivek Mishra  the icons are included in the app

Comment: If your images are in drawable folder, then you should do it like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369814/how-to-access-the-drawable-resources-by-name-in-android